# return item with maximum sort-key in dynamodb

Tags: python, key, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I'm using a python script to access a dynamodb database in AWS.

I have a table with a hash key and sort key.

For a given hash key, I want to find the item with the largest sort key that is less than a certain value. How can I do that?

Alternatively, is there a way to find the previous item from a given key?

I am *not* trying to find the item with the largest *attribute* value (an expensive task in dynamodb), I want the largest *key* value.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the answer,

```
import boto3
import botocore
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr


dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = dynamodb.Table(table_name)

response = table.query(
              Limit = 1,
              ScanIndexForward = False,
              KeyConditionExpression=Key('device').eq(device) & Key('epoch').lte(threshold)
           )
```

Where:

- 'device' is my hash key
- 'epoch' is my sort key
- threshold is the value I want to search below