# return all hash-key items with maximum sort-key in dynamodb using boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, dynamodb-queries

Given a `dynamodb` table with a `hash-key` and `sort-key`, how can `boto3` be used to query all hash-key items where the sort-key is the maximum value for the particular hash-key?

As an example, if the table is

```
HK     SK     Value

A      1      'foo'
       2      'bar'

B      1      'boo'
       2      'far'
       3      'faz'

C      1      'baz'
```

What is the boto3 query to retrieve

```
A      2      'bar'
B      3      'faz'
C      1      'baz'
```

There is [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42520701/return-item-with-maximum-sort-key-in-dynamodb) which doesn't apply to my circumstance because the "last" operation is for a specific hash-key, whereas this query is for all hash-keys.

Thank you in advance for your consideration and response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to achieve this by using single query, what you can do is to have a special row for each of your hash keys like this:

```
      GSI
HK     SK          Value
A  "special_row"   2
A      1          'foo'
A      2          'bar'
B  "special_row"   3
B      1          'boo'
B      2          'far'
B      3          'faz'
C  "special_row"   1
C      1          'baz'
```

Those special rows store the maximum sort key you have seen for give hash key. So whenever you need to insert a new row, you will need to compare that with the existing special row to see if you will need to update that as well.
After that, you can just build a global secondary index on your sort keys and do query like this:
`select * where SK = "special_row"`. Then it should return all the unique hash keys with the maximum sort key now.

Answer (score 3):

This probably isn't the answer you're looking for, but **DynamoDB doesn't have the complex querying capabilities necessary to support this.** What you're trying to do is more suitable for relational databases; unlike most of those, DynamoDB only operates on individual documents and doesn't maintain query state.

There are only two operations that support searching records when you don't know the key(s) ahead of time:

- **Query** requires a partition key, and only searches the documents under that partition key. It's suitable for finding the record with the maximum sort key for a single partition key, as demonstrated in the question you found, but it can't be applied to more than one partition key at a time.
- **Scan** searches the entire table, but it can only apply a filter to each individual record. It doesn't have any concept of grouping and doesn't maintain any state, so it can't keep track of the highest sort key value for each partition key it encounters.

You can see that neither of these operations are exactly suitable for what you want to do: you want to search the entire table, like a scan, but want to treat each set of records under a partition key as a group, like a query.

On top of that, these operations are paged and only search a limited set of data on each call. It's very possible that a single scan operation will cut off in the middle of a set of records with the same partition key. Even if DynamoDB did support stateful queries, it may arrive at the wrong result, because it didn't look at the entire set of records under that partition key.

### Code Solutions

Since you can only achieve this via performing the query in your own code, the easiest solution is to just scan the entire table and keep track of the document with the highest sort key for each partition key grouping. This may be incredibly slow and expensive with large data sets.

If you're worried about the size of your table, you can get innovative and use a second table to store the highest sort key for each partition key using transactional writes. This will still be somewhat expensive with a large data set, but not as expensive as scanning the entire table.

If this is intended to be some sort of versioning system where you usually just want to get the latest version of a document, you may want to consider configuring a table stream, removing the sort key, and just overwriting the entire document. When you overwrite the document, the old document will be written to the stream. You can create a very basic lambda that reads from the stream and writes each old document to an archive table, using the version as a sort key.